# Swift: Force show Navigation Bar in Modal

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following Storyboard Segue in my Swift project:

[image]

The animation is correct, but there is no navigation bar in the destination view controller. I want to force the destination view controller to have a navigation bar. I tried in the destination view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
}
```

Or:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

But it refuses to show any navigation bar.

How can I perform a vertical segue (like "Cover Vertical") but still display a translucent Navigation bar in the destination view controller?

Edit: My Attributes inspector for the destination view controller:

[image]

Comment: Is your destination controller embedded in a navigation controller? Is your segue to the navigation controller or your view controller?

Comment: (Is `self.navigationController` `nil`?)

Comment: `println(self.navigationController)` in my destination view controller prints: `Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x12de38070>)` - my original view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to create the Segue to a Navigation controller instead of your view controller. Navigation bars are only shown for view controllers in a navigation stack. In your case, the source view controller seems to be in a navigation stack but not the presented view controller. Try something like this:

[image]

Comment: it's crazy, but it works) thanks. it's strange, I had similar structure without this intermediate navigation controller in one of my previous projects, and it works there. I mean it displays navigation bar by default

Comment: easy tip: select your modal view, Xcode Editor menu > Embedded In > Navigation Controller. :-)

Comment: Ahh that solved it. One of those storyboard quirks