# Swift: Show a navigation bar/top bar on modal view with delegate

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, uikit

I am trying to force a navigation bar to show on a modal view. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401210/swift-force-show-navigation-bar-in-modal), I am trying to do that by embedding just the modal view, `nextScreenViewController` in a special navigation controller, `nextScreenNavigationController`.

However, I am using delegate patterns to pass data between the initial viewController and `nextScreenViewController`. Before embedding in the navigationController, I was initalizing with the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "goToNextScreen" {      
         let nextScreenDelegate = segue.destinationViewController as! nextScreenViewController
          nextScreenDelegate.delegate = self
     }
}
```

[Some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689261/modal-segue-navigation-bar-dissapears) suggested that, in order to account for `nextScreenNavigationController` I should use code like...

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:   AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "goToNextScreen" {
          let navigation: UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! nextScreenNavigationController
          var nextScreenDelegate = nextScreenViewController.init()
          nextScreenDelegate = navigation.viewControllers[0] as! nextScreenViewController
          nextScreenDelegate.delegate = self
  }
}
```

However, that fails without crashing - no data are passed.

Please comment if you want more of my delegate pattern... I just want to be sure it is not a basic implementation problem. Or, is there a better way to show a nav bar on a modal view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - never mind! I realized that the above code works, and my issue was that I failed to assign the navigationController the class `nextScreenNavigationController` in storyboard.